# Can this MSBuild target be written more simply/elegantly?

Tags: msbuild

My MSBuild knowledge is a bit rusty. I wrote this working target today but I'm sure it can be reduced in size.

Can anyone see how to express this more simply please?

```
 <Target Name="FolderX">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <Dest>$(StandardModelDir)\FolderX</Dest>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <File Include="$(CustDir)\File1.sql">
            <Dest>$(Dest)\Views--Alpha</Dest>
        </File>
        <File Include="$(CustDir)\File2.sql">
            <Dest>$(Dest)\Views--Alpha</Dest>
        </File>
        <File Include="$(CustDir)\File3.sql">
            <Dest>$(Dest)\Views--Bravo</Dest>
        </File>
        <File Include="$(CustDir)\File4.sql">
            <Dest>$(Dest)\Views--Bravo</Dest>
        </File>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Copy
       SourceFiles="@(File)"
       DestinationFolder="%(File.Dest)\.."
    />
</Target>
```

Note that the Files are not recursively stored in the source directory so I cannot use `%(RecursiveDir)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use masks. In your case you can use file extension mask, *.sql

Example from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <ItemGroup>
        <MySourceFiles Include="c:\MySourceTree\**\*.*"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="CopyFiles">
        <Copy
            SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)"
            DestinationFiles="@(MySourceFiles->'c:\MyDestinationTree\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"
        />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: thanks, but that assumes the source files are in the source tree recursively in the same nesting as the destination. That's not true in this case (see edit).